# want to use and operator with or at the same time

Tags: javascript, function, object, operators, type-conversion

```
var obj5 = {a:200, b:200, c:true};
var dataT = 'string' || 'number' || 'boolean' ;
obj5.notType = function(){
  for (var p in this){
    if(typeof(this[p]) == dataT){
      alert("have datatype");}
    }
};
obj5.notType();  // doesn't show alert
```

Here I need to check all the object property data is valid datatype or not, but i can't make it happen. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign an expression to a variable, on the results of evaluating an expression.

`'string' || 'number' || 'boolean' ;` evaluates as `'string'` so you always test to see if the value is a string.

Store your data type names in an array instead. Then use `indexOf` to see if there is a match.

```
var dataT = ['string', 'number', 'boolean'] ;
```

and

```
if ( dataT.indexOf(typeof this[p]) > -1 ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof(this[p]) == 'string' 
|| typeof(this[p]) == 'number' 
|| typeof(this[p]) == 'boolean')
{
 alert("have datatype");
}
```